# How to add an icon outside of my table to the left?

Tags: html

I have a table:

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> ID </th>
            <th> Job</th>
            <th> Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I want to add two icons to the left of the table.  I've tried adding divs, spans, nothing seems to work.  I can see the icon displayed but it's about 20px higher than the table and far left.

Does anyone know how I can align this?

Also, I don't know if it makes a difference, but this table will grow as users input information.  I need the icons to appear on every row.  I already have the functionality to create new rows with user inputs so if I can just figure out how to align the icons on this simple table above then I can replicate for the other rows.

Thank you!

For reference - the icon is

```
class = "mdi mdi-alert"
```

Just thought I would provide that in case someone wanted to give an example like:

```
<div class="mdi mdi-alert">
   <table>
....
   </table>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you need those icons in every row, why not just have a column reserved for the icons?

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions.

A. Use pseudo-elements :

```
tr::before {
    content: 'youricon';
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: 0
}
```

B. Add the icons inside the first cell and move them to the left :

```
.mdi {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: 0
}


<table>
    <tr>
    <td><div class="mdi mdi-alert"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: None of this works for me on Chrome on Mac. It adds a row or a cell to the table, and doesn’t put the icon next to it, but inside said row/cell. What **did** work was adding a div before the first character in the first cell, with CSS position relative and positioning how I wanted it, height and width set to zero.